# CSS layout messed up in firefox but not IE or Opera?

Tags: html, css, xml, layout

For some reason Firefox is messing up the following websites layout, it works fine in IE and Opera though...

http://87.194.141.33/bivakas/shop

I have tried using firebug to find missing divs or anything like that but sadly without success. If anyone would be willing to take a couple minutes to have a look at why this may be happening I would be very grateful.

Thanks!!

Comment: "Works fine here" -- fsvo fine. Make sure you run through all the basic HTML and CSS validators.

Comment: No, it displays with gaps and obvious visual errors in FF (3.6.6, Windows).  It also has scores of HTML and CSS validation errors.

Comment: I have now recoded it with <div> and it works on all browsers. The only problem I have now is that the border of <div id="bvContainer"> does not go down all the divs (ie it is not containing the entire site?! Cheers guys

Answer (score 2):

Start with basic automated QA of the [markup](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F87.194.141.33%2Fbivakas%2Fshop%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2F87.194.141.33%2Fbivakas%2Fshop%2Fthemes%2Fbivakas%2Fcss%2Fglobal.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en)…

… no, scratch that. Start with [not abusing tables for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/).

Opera provide [a good introduction to web development using modern techniques](http://wsc.opera.com/).

Comment: While I appreciate that using tables is old school... this does not help me with the current problem.

Comment: Yes, it does. If you stop throwing garbage at browsers, then they will be better able to cope with it.

Comment: +1 "for general". Although, if a browser does not display a table/css-table correctly, that's still an issue (even if the design/tool choice is questionable).

Answer (score 1):

The entire layout is in an 8 by 9 table, inexplicably wrapped in 2 divs (ID'd as "header" and "bvhead", no less).

It *appears* that the problem is a mismatch between the number of columns, from row to row, and the number of rows, due to math errors in the use of `colspan` and `rowspan`.  But, after a couple of minutes of trying to fix it, I gave it up as a bad job.

**Recommendations:**

1. The site has scores of errors -- which different browsers cleanup in different ways.  [Validate the HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix the errors.  Likewise [validate and fix the CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org).
2. If you **must** use tables, don't wrap the whole site in one monster one!   Minimize side effects and interaction problems by using a new table for each section.
   Lose the misleading and extraneous divs.
   So instead of:

   ```
   <body>
       <div id="header">
           <div id="bvhead">
               <table id="bvmaintable">
                   ... Entire site here!!!
               </table>
           </div>
       </div>
   </body>
   ```

   Use something like:

   ```
   <body>
       <table id="bvHeader">
           ... 
       </table>
       <table id="bvAnnoyingAnimation">
           ... 
       </table>
       <table id="bvMenu">
           ... 
       </table>
       <table id="bvBody">
           ... 
       </table>
       <table id="bvFooter">
           ... 
       </table>
   </body>
   ```

   Note that this allows a different number of columns from one section to the next, is more semantically valid, and makes future cleanup of the table layout easier.
3. Instead of using `rowspan`s, consider using a table-within-a-table-cell.  As ugly as it is, it makes more sense for parts of your layout and eliminates some of the row/column math errors.